# ¿como hago para guardar mas registros en un TXT desde processing?

Tags: processing, txt

una de las dudas que tengo al estar programando un juego algo sencillo es que me encontre con el problema de guardar las puntuaciones en un TXT la cual al principio cuando mueres este toma tu puntuacion y lo guarda en un TXT y despues este lo imprime en el scketch de processing, el problema surge cuando reinicio el juego este no me guarda la nueva puntuacion en el mismo TXT si no que lo que hace es reemplazar como si no huviera registros anteriores este es el apartado que estoy usando para ello 
" if (vida<1) {

```
 String[] lines = loadStrings("puntuaciones.txt");
  String Anterior = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    Anterior = lines[i];
  }


  output.print( Anterior + "Partida : " +bandera +" : "+ (puntaje));

  bandera = bandera +1;
  output.flush(); 
  output.close();


}
```

pero no se como hacer que en vez de que me genere una nueva puntuacion y tome esos puntos y los guarde en el TXT pero sin reemplazar o tomar el lugar de la puntuacion anterior

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas! Intenta hacer un `append()`, te dejo documentación sobre la sentencia: https://processing.org/reference/append_.html

El problema es que no necesitas la variable "Anterior", simplemente haciendo un `append(lines, "<contenido que quieras añadir>");` sería suficiente.